# How to check git repository url of project in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

See every time to check repository url I have to go under .git folder and check config for repository url.

Is there any way to check the project repository url from eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

(June 2014) See the section "[Remotes Repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Remote_Repositories)" or the [EGit manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide):

> The "Remotes" node allows for browsing and editing Remote configurations.
>   Each Remote configuration has a name and either a Push Specification, a Fetch Specification, or both.
>
> **If a "Remote Configuration" node or any of its children is selected, the Properties view will show a summary of the Remote configuration**.

You should see the url of the upstream repo in the `Git Repositories` view:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/e2/RepoMgrRemoteConfig.png]

Note that, in command line, instead of getting in the `.git/config` directly, you can type:

```
git remote -v
```

---

Update October 2016, with [Git in Eclipse](https://eclipse.github.io/):

As mentioned in the "[Pushing to other Repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pushing_to_other_Repositories)", you also see the remote url with the "[Configure push url](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Configuring_upstream_push)" dialog:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/e7/Egit-3.1-ConfigurePushToUpstream.png]

Answer (score 0):

From the package explorer view: right click on project you are working on =>Team=>Remote=>configure push to upstream.
You should now see the remove URL
Note: This is for Eclipse Neon release